# How to delete string array from a struct in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct, char

I wonder how to delete string array from a structure.

For example I have a structure and an array defined this way:

```
struct dataofcall {
    char day[25];
    char country[25];
    char startofthecall[6];
    char endofthecall[6];
};

dataofcall call[MAX];
```

Then I ask user to input a number of calls that he wants to enter: for example: `3`.

Then with a for cycle user enters information about `1`, `2`, and `3` call.
Like this:

```
Monday Luxembourg 22:12 22:15
Tuesday Germany 12:21 14:16
Tuesday France 09:08 23:23
```

And `call[0]` will look like this:

```
call[0].day[25] = "Monday";
call[0].country[25] = "Luxembourg";
call[0].startofthecall[6] = "22:12";
call[0].endofthecall[6] = "22:15";
```

call[1] will look like:

```
call[1].day[25] = "Germany";
```

etc.

So, now I need to delete information from `call`, for example `2` and `3`, that `1` and if are any other calls, will be untouched.

I just don't understand how can I delete it, not how to enter information about calls or whatever. Just want to ask help for algorithm or small cycle that will help me in deleting an string from struct array.

I tried to do this:

```
strcpy(call[0].country, "Data is deleted.");
```

But it looks somewhat incorrect, like it should be better way in doing it, that I can't find.

Comment: You cannot affirmatively delete an array, except to the extent that you can allow or cause the lifetime of the array object to end.  That's not an alternative in your example case.  You can, however, overwrite its contents with different contents (not exceeding the length of the array).  Your `strcpy()` call appears to be a correct example of doing so.  You could also consider simply writing a string terminator at index zero of the array, after which string functions will interpret the array contents as an empty string.

Comment: If you want to delete the entire entry, add an `int inuse;` field to the structure. Set it to `1` for calendar entries that are valid, `0` for one that are deleted. There's no need to delete the strings.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, I just simplified that, my bad

Comment: @JohnBollinger so I guess it is the way, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete (as in free the memory), but you can do something like

call[0].country[0] = '\0';

This makes the string handling functions see call[0].country as being an empty string because the first character is now a \0 which is the string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

If the array was declared with automatic or static storage duration:

```
dataofcall call[MAX];
```

then there's no way to *delete* it.

The array will cease to exist (in case of automatic storage duration) when control reaches the closing brace of the block it was declared in. Static storage duration, however, exists for the lifetime of a program and wouldn't go out of scope.

If you instead allocated the memory dynamically on the heap with something like this:

```
struct dataofcall **call = malloc (MAX * sizeof (struct dataofcall);
```

Then you can delete (or free) the memory allocated from the heap with a call to `free()`.

```
free (call);
```